# Intellisense for HTML controls in MVC4 razor engine in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor

I am unable to get intellisense for HTML Controls in MVC4 Razor Engine in Visual Studio 2012. I am able to get intellisense for Razor code. Any help is appreciated. Please suggest a solution

What I have tried:

I tried by installing mvc5 through nuget in visual studio 2012

Comment: You wont get help with your html, you'll only get help with  your Razor when you have a strongly typed view \ model

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Web Tools 2013` for solve this problem. See [Razor Intellisense does not work in Views](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q584571) for more information.